# Uninstall Java from registry/system after manually deleting folder

Tags: windows-xp, java, windows-registry, uninstall, control-panel

When I go to 'Add or Remove Programs' in Windows XP, I see entries for some old JDK installations such as 'Java SE Development Kit 6 Update 16'. When I click the Remove button I get the message 'Fatal error during installation'.

I suspect this is because at some point I manually deleted the folder from the filesystem. If this is the case is there anyway to get rid of the entry in 'Add or Remove Programs' dialog? Basically I just want to get rid of all traces of the program.

I also tried CCleaner since that provides uninstall functionality. When I uninstall using that, it seems to succeed but then I reopen CCleaner and the entry is back so it obviously didn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 1):

[KB310750 - Removing Invalid Entries in the Add/Remove Programs Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310750):

> `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

---

Really should be using the uninstall. Just deleting the folder is almost certainly going to leave things behind (e.g. COM object registrations, services, scheduled tasks).

Comment: Useful answer -- but after following the steps the invalid entries were still listed in the Add/Remove Programs tool. There must be some other additional registry location.